# How to insert data which does not have specific sequence?

Tags: mysql, multidimensional-array

My array print_r  is :

```
Array
(
    [email] => xxx@cs.caddmu.edu
    [attempt] => 0
    [timestamp] => 1369676665
    [smtp-id] => <1369676650.51a39b6a76cec@www.openaccesspub.org>
    [response] => 451 4.2.0 Temporarily Grey listed.  Try again in a couple of minutes 
    [category] => Invitation
    [event] => deferred
)
Array
(
    [email] => reidsdds@cs.cdsmu.edu
    [timestamp] => 1369676845
    [smtp-id] => <1369676650.51a39b6a76cec@www.openaccesspub.org>
    [response] => 250 2.0.0 r4RHlOGH017661 Message accepted for delivery 
    [category] => Invitation
    [event] => delivered
)
Array
(
    [email] => jrai@openhh.com
    [timestamp] => 1369678994
    [smtp-id] => <1369678990.51a3a48e93428@ohhpb.org>
    [category] => Reviewers
    [event] => processed
)
Array
(
    [email] => sss@lusst.fi
    [timestamp] => 1369678997
    [smtp-id] => <1369678990.51a3a48e93428@oub.org>
    [response] => 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 02C103F0454 
    [category] => Revie
    [event] => delivered
)
```

And the tables have these rows :

> event_id, event, email, category, timestamp, response, attempt, url, status, reason, type, action, m_id .

I'm trying to insert in mysql table with this  :-

```
foreach ($temp_array as $key => $poke) 
{ 
    mysql_query ("INSERT INTO temp_array (email,timestamp,category,event,response,attempt,reason,o_id,operator,action,...)VALUES ('$poke[email]','$poke[timestamp]','$poke[category]','$poke[event]',.... )" ); 
}
```

But i'm getting error " Undefined index: category in

```
  C:\xampp\htdocs\eembeta\array_temp.php on line 34
```

How to insert data which does not have specific sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about sequence, but $poke['category'] does not exist in that array (element to insert). Be sure that all array fields you want to use are initialised:

```
$poke['category'] = $poke['category'] ? $poke['category'] : '';
```

That code means: Is that field set? yes: use it. no: use empty string.
That way $poke['category'] is known, so you get no error.

Btw, you can replace '' by 0, null or whatever you need.

Comment: But Still i'm getting the error..! 
foreach($temp_array as $key => $poke) {
 
 $poke['category'] = $poke['category'] ? $poke['category'] : '';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO temp_array 
 
 (`email`,`timestamp`,`category`,`event`)VALUES  ('$poke[email]','$poke[timestamp]','$poke[category]','$poke[event]' )" );
 }

Comment: You seem to be using single quotes try replace with : ('.$poke[email].','.$poke[timestamp].','.$poke[category].','.$poke[event].' )" );

Comment: If not in double quotes, use single quotes around the keys. .','.$poke['category'].',' - easy rule: every string is quoted. In your case, the whole SQL part and the array keys are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the data inside your query, sanatize it to avoid SQL Injections. To achieve this, consider using PDO.

Answering your question

For each key, create a temporary variable like:
$event = isset($_GET ['event']) ?$_GET ['event'] : null;